# How can i remove duplicate encoding meta tag

Tags: 7, meta-tags

I have repeated `charset` meta tag in all my drupal pages. I have been using my [metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module.

To optimize SEO results, this error is reported as primary to fix.

I have used jquery(ready & load event) to remove from client side, removes in dom element but the page source shows 2 charsets.

[image]

No configuration in meta tag refers to charset.

Comment: Whatever reporting tool is telling you this is bad for SEO is spouting nonsense. It's not ideal, but it will have precisely practical effect on SEO. Also, trying to remove head tags using JavaScript is a waste of time, you need to do it on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag is appearing twice in the rendered HTML, chances are one of the instances is hard-coded in your theme's html.tpl.php template, while the other is inserted by the metatag module.

I'd recommend checking your theme templates. In some cases, freelancers with little Drupal knowledge may create several page level templates duplicating the head, header, and footer markup too.

As Alfred noted in his comment, removing this tag should be done server side and not via javascript.  While it does add a few bytes to download of the page, it does not critically effect search engines from detecting the page's content for indexing.